# Changing coefficients modulo p in a SymPy polynomial

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, polynomials

I took a cryptography course this semester in graduate school, and once of the topics we covered was NTRU. I am trying to code this in pure Python, purely as a hobby. When I attempt to find a polynomial's inverse modulo p (in this example p = 3), SymPy always returns negative coefficients, when I want strictly positive coefficients. Here is the code I have. I'll explain what I mean.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import GF

def make_poly(N,coeffs):
    """Create a polynomial in x."""
    x = sym.Symbol('x')
    coeffs = list(reversed(coeffs))
    y = 0
    for i in range(N):
        y += (x**i)*coeffs[i]
    y = sym.poly(y)
    return y

N = 7
p = 3
q = 41
f = [1,0,-1,1,1,0,-1]

f_poly = make_poly(N,f)

x = sym.Symbol('x')

Fp = sym.polys.polytools.invert(f_poly,x**N-1,domain=GF(p))
Fq = sym.polys.polytools.invert(f_poly,x**N-1,domain=GF(q))

print('\nf =',f_poly)
print('\nFp =',Fp)
print('\nFq =',Fq)
```

In this code, `f_poly` is a polynomial with degree at most 6 (its degree is at most `N-1`), whose coefficients come from the list `f` (the first entry in `f` is the coefficient on the highest power of `x`, continuing in descending order).

Now, I want to find the inverse polynomial of `f_poly` in the convolution polynomial ring `Rp = (Z/pZ)[x]/(x^N - 1)(Z/pZ)[x]` (similarly for `q`). The output of the print statements at the bottom are:

```
f = Poly(x**6 - x**4 + x**3 + x**2 - 1, x, domain='ZZ')
Fp = Poly(x**6 - x**5 + x**3 + x**2 + x + 1, x, modulus=3)
Fq = Poly(8*x**6 - 15*x**5 - 10*x**4 - 20*x**3 - x**2 + 2*x - 4, x, modulus=41)
```

These polynomials are correct in modulus, but I would like to have positive coefficients everywhere, as later on in the algorithm there is some centerlifting involved, so I need to have positive coefficients. The results should be

```
Fp = x^6 + 2x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
Fq = 8x^6 + 26x^5 + 31x^4 + 21x^3 + 40x^2 + 2x + 37
```

The answers I'm getting are correct in modulus, but I think that SymPy's `invert` is changing some of the coefficients to negative variants, instead of staying inside the mod.

Is there any way I can update the coefficients of this polynomial to have only positive coefficients in modulus, or is this just an artifact of SymPy's function? I want to keep the SymPy `Poly` format so I can use some of its embedded functions later on down the line. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be down to how the finite field object implemented in `GF` "wraps" integers around the given modulus. The default behavior is `symmetric`, which means that any integer `x` for which `x % modulo <= modulo//2` maps to `x % modulo`, and otherwise maps to `(x % modulo) - modulo`. So `GF(10)(5) == 5`, whereas `GF(10)(6) == -4`. You can make `GF` always map to positive numbers instead by passing the `symmetric=False` argument:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import GF

def make_poly(N, coeffs):
    """Create a polynomial in x."""
    x = sym.Symbol('x')
    coeffs = list(reversed(coeffs))
    y = 0
    for i in range(N):
        y += (x**i)*coeffs[i]
    y = sym.poly(y)
    return y

N = 7
p = 3
q = 41
f = [1,0,-1,1,1,0,-1]

f_poly = make_poly(N,f)

x = sym.Symbol('x')

Fp = sym.polys.polytools.invert(f_poly,x**N-1,domain=GF(p, symmetric=False))
Fq = sym.polys.polytools.invert(f_poly,x**N-1,domain=GF(q, symmetric=False))

print('\nf =',f_poly)
print('\nFp =',Fp)
print('\nFq =',Fq)
```

Now you'll get the polynomials you wanted. The output from the `print(...)` statements at the end of the example should look like:

```
f = Poly(x**6 - x**4 + x**3 + x**2 - 1, x, domain='ZZ')
Fp = Poly(x**6 + 2*x**5 + x**3 + x**2 + x + 1, x, modulus=3)
Fq = Poly(8*x**6 + 26*x**5 + 31*x**4 + 21*x**3 + 40*x**2 + 2*x + 37, x, modulus=41)
```

Mostly as a note for my own reference, here's how you would get `Fp` using Mathematica:

```
Fp = PolynomialMod[Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod`PolynomialPowerMod[x^6 - x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - 1, -1, x, x^7 - 1], 3]
```

output:

```
1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + 2 x^5 + x^6
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @tel. That is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't even think to check the GF module.

Comment: Believe me, it was not obvious. When investigating I didn't find a single source that defines modulo or polynomial rings in terms of that symmetric behavior. Mathematica also disagrees.

Comment: I'm not getting where `Poly` is imported from

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack That's not python code, that's the output from the `print('\nf =',f_poly)...` statements at the end of the example